# Argument of type “char *” is incompatible with parameter of type “STARTUPINFO”

Tags: c++

My name is David, and i need for help!
It's my problem >>

```
sprintf_s(cmd_args, "\"%s\" -d", exe_path);
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {0};
    memset(&pi, 0, sizeof(pi));
    memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    CreateProcessA(exe_path, cmd_args, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

Error: (( What's wrong? ))

```
&si << It's problem
Argument of type “char *” is incompatible with parameter of type “STARTUPINFO”
```

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: You want to use CreateProcess instead of CreateProcessA. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Where exactly do you get the error? Are you sure that it happens in `CreateProcessA()` call? (and yes, you should use `CreateProcess()` instead). Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want to get any help.

Comment: I found out what was wrong, but thank you for your answers!
I replace the STARTUPINFO si; to STARTUPINFOA si;

Comment: You are passing the wrong arguments to `sprintf_s` , you need a length specifier to go with `%s` in that function

Answer (score 0):

If you add an A or W suffix on these Windows API's, you must do so consistently: `STARTUPINFO` goes with `CreateProcess`, `STARTUPINFOA` with `CreateProcessA` and `STARTUPINFOW` with `CreateProcessW`.

The difference is what type of string you need, `""` (A) or `L""` (W). The versions without suffix are macros that expand to either A or W depending on compilation settings.